# Does ayone know how to replace space with nothing at all in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I want to replace " " with "" (nothing) on notepad++ .

does anyone know how I can do this?

see the example below.

from:

a b c d

to abcd

Comment: What happens when you use the normal Replace dialog (CTRL+H)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ctrl+H

Set 'Find What' to [press the space bar], then set Replace with to blank [delete everything out]

Click Replace All

[image]